# Suggest a page title to users

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

On the add page of a new Plone Page i want to suggest a title to the user derived from the Folder title by adding it into the title form field.
What is the best practice on implementing that behavior in my Plone instance?

Comment: Could you try the JS-solution, something unclear, any hurdles? To me e.g., a hurdle with Plone-5 would be, how to simply add a JS/CSS-file...

Comment: If the person who asked could please help us to improve our answers, that would be nice.

Comment: So I tried solving the problem with the Monkey patching suggestion, simply because I have no experience in the usage Javascript at all.
Monkey patching the _get_title function as suggested only works in the "edit"-form, the "add"-form does not call that function. So a custom form would be necessary.
Also a suggested title in the edit form will not be saved unless the user modifies it, which is another problem.
Third of all I have a problem getting the title of the folder. I tried to call _get_title on the folder but it seems to return nothing

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I can't help you further with the patching-proposals, but you could research how to add a JS-file and simply paste the lines of the answer into it. If the docs can't help you, you could open a new quest "How to add a JS-file in Plone-5". Anotherway could be to make a subscriber listen to the creation of Documents and dynamically add a default-value for the title field.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution can be to use Javascript, respectively jQuery:

```
(function($) { $(document).ready(function() {

  // A Dexterity-based document is added:
  if( window.location.href.endsWith('/++add++Document') ) {

    // Grab the parent's title of the current title-tag's content:
    var title = $('title')[0].innerHTML.split(' — ')[0]

    // Prefill the new document's title-field with the parent's title:
    $('#form-widgets-IDublinCore-title').val(title)
  }

  // An Archetypes-based document is added:
  if( window.location.href.indexOf('/portal_factory/Document/') > -1 ) {
    var parentUrl= document.referrer
    var parentTitleEleId = 'parent-fieldname-title'

    // Provide ele to load parent's title into:
    var loadEle = document.createElement('span')

    // Load parent's title into ele:
    $(loadEle).load(parentUrl + ' #' + parentTitleEleId, function() {

      // After loading finished, fetch parent-title of ele, remove
      // trailing spaces and set it into the new doc's title-field:
      $('#title').val(loadEle.childNodes[0].innerHTML.trim())

      // Thy had served y'er purpose, vanish:
      loadEle.remove()

    });

  }

});})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

More to MonkeyPatching can you find in the [Docs](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/monkeypatch.html). Another solution is, you can register your own AddForm and set the Value of the Textline-Widget. To create a Custom AddForm look at the [Docs](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/custom-add-and-edit-forms.html#custom-add-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can monkeypatch or subclass the `Basic metadata` behavior to modify the behavior of _get_title: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.dexterity/blob/master/plone/app/dexterity/behaviors/metadata.py#L350-L351